# Properties missing in docx file

Tags: java, ms-word, base64

I am having a situation where i receive a ms-word (docx) document as a stream/bytearray from a webservice.

I then try to recreate the file, giving it the same name and content as before.

If i compare the original file and the one created after the download, then they are identical.

However, when i try to open the new one in word i get an error, and if accept the riscs i can open it.

If i look at the properties af the file in windows, the new one is missing a lot of information.

Any one know how to recreate the properties so the file can be opened without errors?

---

Just an extra piece of information.. If i use .doc (word97-2003) documents all is working fine, only .docx documents are a problem (also .xlsx and all the office 2007-2010 documents).

This is my code creating the files..

```
private static void saveBytesAsFile(String path, String filename, byte[] data){
    try {
        File dir = new File(path);
        dir.mkdirs();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(path + "/" + filename);
        os.write(data);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        fnfe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I compared the original and the recreated file in notepad++, and got the result that they are identical.

This is how i see that some properties are missing.

[Image of properties](http://www.knk.dk/tmp/propertiesMatch.PNG)

These are the warnings i get from word:

If i press ok on the first and yes on the second i can open the document anyway.

[Word Warnings](http://www.knk.dk/tmp/wordWarning.PNG)

Comment: You should include the code that recreates the file. Might help people figure out what's going on.

Comment: How do you compare the original file and the downloaded file? What attributes tell you that these are exactly the same files?

Comment: If you have solved your problem please post an answer.  This is the accepted way of doing it on SO.  Also, do not edit your title to solved.

Comment: I will do so... sry for breaking protocol..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **SOLUTION**

It turned out that there were no problem with the properties.

It was simply so that somewhere in the services that provided the document data an extra blank character was added at the end of the file data.

This resulted in a mismatch of the expected file length and the actual one, and therefore the office components complained when trying to open the documents.

And this also prevented the properties of the file to be parsed.

What was pretty annoying, was that file comparison tools did not catch this. (Or maybe there need to be some configuration of trailing spaces not beeing ignored.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are asked to "accept the risks" then this sounds more like the default Word behaviour when downloading documents from the internet, not an error. You can change the Word behaviour from the Word Options, Trust Center (assuming you are using Word 2007 or later).

So I doubt that the missing properties are an issue. It is possible to change the creation date of the document that you are re-creating, by changing the system clock before building your new document (based on the previous document's content). I am not recommending these steps.